# Sort array of objects by two keys with equality

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort an array of objects by two keys, where the first one is sorted in an ascending matter and the second is sorted by equality. What I attempted, sorted the array only by the first attribute:

```
var test_array = [{number: 1, color: "#EEEE23"},
                  {number: 4, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 5, color: "#EEEE23"},
                  {number: 1, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 6, color: "#CCCC23"},
                  {number: 1, color: "#EEEE23"},
                  {number: 2, color: "#EEEE23"},
                  {number: 3, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 1, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 2, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 3, color: "#EEEE23"},
                  {number: 2, color: "#EEEE23"},
                  {number: 3, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 2, color: "#FFFFFF"}]

test_array.sort(function(x,y){
    return x.number - y.number || x.color === y.color
```

My goal is to get the array to look like this, where the colors are also sorted:

```
var test_array = [{number: 1, color: "#EEEE23"},
                  {number: 1, color: "#EEEE23"},
                  {number: 1, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 1, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 2, color: "#EEEE23"},
                  {number: 2, color: "#EEEE23"},
                  {number: 2, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 2, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 3, color: "#EEEE23"},
                  {number: 3, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 3, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 4, color: "#FFFFFF"},
                  {number: 5, color: "#EEEE23"},
                  {number: 6, color: "#CCCC23"}]
```

Is my solution too naive and using equality in to sort does not work that easily?

Comment: The second one cannot be used that way right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an equality comparison does not make sense because the `sort()` function expects the return value to be a number; equality comparison returns `true` or `false`. Instead, you can use the String `.localeCompare()` method:

```
return x.number - y.number || x.color.localeCompare(y.color);
```

The `.localeCompare()` function does exactly what you want, returning -1, 0, or 1 based on the lexicographic ordering of the strings.